# Converting a String to a String of Binary

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

My goal is to be able to convert a string into binary code that is still a string. I am able to turn the string into byte[] but not back to a string without decoding it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Convert method for that:

```
byte [] bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (inputText);
string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String (bytesToEncode);
```

Comment: I guess that's exactly what he wants. 'to a string of binary'

Comment: Yes I missed the part where he wanted "still as a string"

Answer (score 1):

If you can encode/decode a *byte*, e.g.

```
private static String ToBinary(Byte value) {
  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder(8);

  Sb.Length = 8;

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    Sb[7 - i] = (Char) ('0' + value % 2);

    value /= 2;
  }

  return Sb.ToString();
}

private static Byte FromBinary(String value) {
  int result = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
    result = result * 2 + value[i] - '0';

  return (Byte) result;
}
```

You can easily encode/decode a *whole string*:

```
  // Encoding... 
  String source = "abc";

  // 011000010110001001100011
  String result = String.Join("", UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source).Select(x => ToBinary(x)));

  ... 

  // Decoding...
  List<Byte> codes = new List<Byte>();

  for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i += 8) 
    codes.Add(FromBinary(result.Substring(i, 8)));

  // abc
  String sourceBack = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(codes.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
string str = "Welcome"; 
byte []arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
```